# How to deal with http code errors filling select options with observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, httpclient, formbuilder

I filling some select options with observables by calling web services. The point is I am trying to get the http code errors in order to hide the form (if any of these the http code is different to 200) and show a message to the user.

Can someone suggest me a good practice to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Repo: https://github.com/jreategui07/testing-subscriptions-form

Mock server runs with: mockserver -p 8080 -m mock

GET.mock

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive

[
   { "error": "c1", "error_des": "any error" }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an error handler to all of your select observables. Notice in this I am only gathering the last error and hide the form so if there are multiple error you can use an array to the formHasError variable.

- Define a variable which will track the formErrors:

```
formHasError: string[] = [];
```

- Create an error function to handle the error

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
errorFn = catchError(e => {
  const err = e && e.error && e.error[0] && e.error[0].error_des;
  if(err){
    this.formHasError.push(err);
  }
  return [];
});
```

- In your component the select observables are modified to

```
this.colorSC$ = catalogueService.getColors().pipe(this.errorFn);
this.brandSC$ = catalogueService.getBrands().pipe(this.errorFn);
this.sizeSC$ = catalogueService.getSizes().pipe(this.errorFn);
this.fruitSC$ = catalogueService.getFruits().pipe(this.errorFn);
```

- In your template add formHasError

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="anyForm" *ngIf="!formHasError.length">
...
</form>
<div class="error" *ngIf="formHasError.length">
  Form has some errors: 
  <p *ngFor="let err of formHasError">{{err}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks, It worked fine, just when I try to push error messages in an Array, for any reason pipes() are not executed. Do you know what could be happening?

Comment: ```formHasError: Array<string>;``` ```errorFn = catchError((e: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    this.formHasError.push(e.message);
    return [];
  });```

Comment: updated for error array. Please mark this if it has worked for you

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, try to paste the relevant code here so that other users can see what you're trying to do. Your relevant code is your catalogue.service.ts:

```typescript
export class CatalogueService {

  requestOptions: any;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
    });
    this.requestOptions = { headers: headers, observe: 'response' };
  }
  getColors() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getColors', this.requestOptions).pipe(map(response => response['body']));
  }
  getBrands() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getBrands', this.requestOptions).pipe(map(response => response['body']));
  }
  getSizes() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getSizes', this.requestOptions).pipe(map(response => response['body']));
  }
  getFruits() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getFruits', this.requestOptions).pipe(map(response => response['body']));
  }
}
```

In particular, since you're already correctly observing the `response`, you can simply check which is the response type:

```typescript
this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getColors', this.requestOptions)
.pipe(
  map(response => !response.ok ? 
                  throw new Error('Request error, reponse code: ' + response.status : 
                  response['body'])
);
```

Note that throwing an Error inside a `map` will cause the observable to error, and so you can deal with it on your code that calls the request like so:

```typescript
this.service.getColors().pipe(
  catchError((error) => /* do something with that error */
);
```

All that said, you did ask for *best practices* dealing with this. In that case, I recommend looking into [Http Interceptors](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) if you want to deal with all Http responses in a similar manner(like logging them somewhere, or showing a tooltip informing the user that a request failed, etc). Interceptors enable you to create module-wide or even app-wide behavior over all responses called from within a module/the app.